# PHP erros/warnings parametro 1 & 2

Tags: php, sql

No meu código PHP aparecem os seguintes "warnings":

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given
>   in on line 8
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in on line 9

Sinceramente não percebo o que isto quer dizer na pratica, o que é o parametro 2? Eu não entendo muito bem quando me aparecem estes warnigns.

Segue o codigo PHP:

```
<?php
include("config.php");
if($_GET['key'] && $_GET['reset'])
{
    $email=password_hash($_GET['key'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $pass=password_hash($_GET['reset'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
    $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT email, password FROM registo where email='$email' and password='$pass'");
    $r = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // Linha 8
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($r); // Linha 9
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)==1)
    {
?>
<html>
    <form method="post" action="update_newpassword.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="
<?php echo $email;?>">
        <p>
            Enter New password
        </p>
        <input type="password" name='password'>
        <input type="submit" name="submit_password">
    </form>
</html>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Remova esse `$r` e use o `$sql` no `mysqli_num_rows()`. Você está passando o retorno de `mysqli_query` para o segundo `mysqli_query` e não uma instrução SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você está passando uma `query` como parâmetro no lugar do `SQL` na linha 8.

Remova a linha 8, pois não é necessária, e altere a linha 9 (que se tornará linha 8) trocando a variável `$r` pela `$sql`:

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
```

Altere a linha 10 (que ficará como linha 9) colocando o `$count` ao invés de repetir o `mysqli_num_rows`:

```
 if($count==1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente estas duas linhas estão fazendo a mesma coisa

```
$sql=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT email, password FROM registo where email='$email' and password='$pass'");
    $r = mysqli_query($conn, $sql); // Linha 8
```

Utilize essa passando o comando `$sql`

```
$count = mysqli_num_rows($r); // Linha 9
```